# Enter start and end dates, divide total days by months (minus holidays)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel 2013, I am attempting to divide total numbers of days in a period by month, excluding specific holidays and weekends. The total numbers would be calculated from user-entered start and end dates. I am able to calculate the total number of days for the period using NETWORKDAYS.

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A3, B3, Holidays!$A$2:$A$50)
```

I am also able to calculate the total of number of days for each month using NETWORKDAYS. Below is my example for January.

```
=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,1,31), Holidays!$A$2:$A$50)
```

I have yet to structure arguments that account for the user-entered dates by month. To illustrate, here's is a screenshot of what I would like to accomplish, but with formulas: 
[image]

I have hundreds of cases to enter, and am hoping I can calculate the months with start and end dates rather than entering them manually.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: they all have the same columns?

Comment: I would ask the same question as @Fabricator, will the columns always be in the same order? (i.e. `Aug -> Jun`)

Comment: Yes. They are based on an academic calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below appears to be working for me, though it's kind of gnarly. As a note, to make this work, each of your column headers should be the first of the month (like Aug 1, 2013). But you can format these dates so they just show up as the month abbreviations.

[image]

Formula to put in D3 and then pull across and down:

```
=IF((IF(AND($A3<D$1,$B3>(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS(D$1,(E$1-1),Holidays!$A$2:$A$50),IF(AND($A3>D$1,$B3>(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS($A3,(E$1-1),Holidays!$A$2:$A$50),IF(AND($A3<D$1,$B3<(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS(D$1,$B3,Holidays!$A$2:$A$50),IF(AND($A3>D$1,$B3<(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS($A3,$B3,Holidays!$A$2:$A$50))))))<0,0,(IF(AND($A3<D$1,$B3>(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS(D$1,(E$1-1),Holidays!$A$2:$A$50),IF(AND($A3>D$1,$B3>(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS($A3,(E$1-1),Holidays!$A$2:$A$50),IF(AND($A3<D$1,$B3<(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS(D$1,$B3,Holidays!$A$2:$A$50),IF(AND($A3>D$1,$B3<(E$1-1)),NETWORKDAYS($A3,$B3,Holidays!$A$2:$A$50)))))))
```

Comment: This might be the formula for `D3`?

Comment: Sure enough. Thanks! Edited it to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Liza! This has been a tremendous help already. However, it appears that the formula has issues with end dates, as illustrated here: http://i.imgur.com/lyMea9R.png I'm wondering if the difference could somehow be subtracted from the Total Days column. '=NETWORKDAYS(A2, B2, Holidays!$A$2:$A$50)'

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I solved my issue by adding a column heading for July. I had also tweaked your formula slightly in my last screenshot, not knowing any better, but I reverted to your original. Problem solved! Thanks again, @Liza. I am beyond grateful. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! That's a good point that the final column will be a problem. As you mention, adding a column for the next month after the end of the academic year should work. You could also replace all the references that are E$1-1 in the original formula with DATE(2014,6,30) just in the June column.