# With a certain date period, generate new rows based on months passed

Tags: excel, vba, date, duplicates

We have a product manufacturer and we ""employ"" (informally) everyone who wants to help and we pay them based on how many days they work (in the end of each semester), the problem with this is that we can't properly control cash flows. Mainly because we have a lot of people working from one week to two months. What we have now it's a simple excel sheet applying a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000954/enter-start-and-end-dates-divide-total-days-by-months-minus-holidays) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012017/formula-to-calculate-days-by-month-between-two-dates-for-future-periods-only?newreg=eba642b0bdff4cc8ad8b9a3ebe1162da).

[image: The Current System]

Though very useful and easy to read for our accountant it takes a lot of time to process (this worksheet stores almost everything in the company, +50k records and ~10mb of data) and we still have to process payments for each month, each worker by hand.
I want to build an VBA script that can store a simple excel function able to split periods in months (displayed as new rows) or just copy/paste rows and override them with the new periods, something like this:

[image: Desired System]

I managed to detect if x period involves more than one months and copy/paste it in other sheet but I can't figure a method/logic on VBA able to do that. Any hints appreciated.

```
Sub mainFunc()
Hoja1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim dateS As Date 'Start Date
Dim dateE As Date 'End Date

For i = 2 To Hoja1
    If IsDate(Range("$B2")) And IsDate(Range("$C2")) Then
        dateS = Range("$B2")
        dateE = Range("$C2")
        If Month(dateE) > Month(dateS) Then
            'If end month is lesser or equal to start date then
            'The month spliter should go here and it should copypaste it in another sheet
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            Hoja2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Hoja2 + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

            Else
            'Else (same month) should just copypaste the same row, no changes
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            Hoja2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Hoja2 + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
    End If

Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Why M-F workdays in original and non-inclusive days of month (EOM-SOM) in the revised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- Your source data is on a worksheet called `"Sheet1"` with `"member"` in column A, `"day start"` in column B, `"day exit"` in column C
- And you're outputting the data to a worksheet called `"Sheet2"`

The code below should you give some idea to achieve what you're after (it gives me what you show in your second screenshot, except for the days worked figure since I use `NETWORKDAYS` function).

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitPayDataIntoMonths()

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastSourceRow As Long
    lastSourceRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim sourceRowIndex As Long

    Dim destinationRowIndex As Long
    destinationRowIndex = 1 ' Skip first row/headers

    Dim startDate As Variant
    Dim endDate As Variant
    Dim dateIndex As Date

    For sourceRowIndex = 2 To lastSourceRow ' Skip first row/headers.
        startDate = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, "B").Value
        endDate = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, "C").Value

        ' Validate dates before looping through them to prevent unwanted behaviour later
        If Not IsDate(startDate) Or Not IsDate(endDate) Then
            MsgBox ("Invalid date encountered in row '" & sourceRowIndex & "' of sheet '" & sourceSheet.Name & "'." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Code will stop running now.")
            Application.Goto sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, "B")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf startDate > endDate Then
            MsgBox ("'Start date' exceed 'end date' on row '" & sourceRowIndex & "' of sheet '" & sourceSheet.Name & "'." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Code will stop running now.")
            Application.Goto sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, "B")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For dateIndex = startDate To endDate
            destinationRowIndex = destinationRowIndex + 1

            destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "A").Value = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, "A").Value
            destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "B").Value = dateIndex

            dateIndex = Application.Min(Application.EoMonth(dateIndex, 0), endDate)
            destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "C").Value = dateIndex
        Next dateIndex

    Next sourceRowIndex

    destinationSheet.Range("D2:D" & destinationRowIndex).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)" 'Days worked
    destinationSheet.Range("E2:E" & destinationRowIndex).Formula = "=D2*15" ' Pay, same daily rate assumed for everyone (based on screenshot in question), but change as necessary

End Sub
```

You can obviously tweak the formulas that get written to `destinationSheet`, as I have made some assumptions that probably aren't true for every "member".

---

**Edit:**

`NETWORKDAYS` function has a third parameter named `Holidays`, which you can use to specify dates you want to exclude. Depends on how you want to implement it.

**Approach 1**

If you store all dates which are holidays in range `"Z1:Z5"` on `"Sheet1"` (for example), you can change this line in the code:

```
destinationSheet.Range("D2:D" & destinationRowIndex).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)" 'Days worked
```

to:

```
destinationSheet.Range("D2:D" & destinationRowIndex).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2,'Sheet1'!$Z$1:$Z$5)" 'Days worked
```

And it should automatically do what you need.

**Approach 2**

If you instead want to store them in some VBA variable (and not on the sheet), then try replacing:

```
destinationSheet.Range("D2:D" & destinationRowIndex).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2)" 'Days worked
```

with:

```
Dim Holidays As Variant
Holidays = Array(#1/10/2019#, #1/28/2019#) ' Add as many dates as you need to. You can also add dates with DateSerial() function instead of literals, if needed.

destinationSheet.Range("D2:D" & destinationRowIndex).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B1,C1,{" & holidaysToString(Holidays) & "})"
```

and put this function in the same module as your code:

```
Private Function holidaysToString(ByVal Holidays As Variant) As String
    ' https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7 says to avoid putting dates as "text"
    '"Important:  Dates should be entered by using the DATE function, or as results of other formulas or functions. For example, use DATE(2012,5,23) for the 23rd day of May, 2012. Problems can occur if dates are entered as text."

    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(Holidays) To UBound(Holidays)
        Holidays(index) = CStr(CDbl(Holidays(index)))
    Next index
    holidaysToString = VBA.Strings.Join(Holidays, ",")
End Function
```

This will result in a hard coded array of numbers (representing holidays) within the formula.

Am sure there are other ways to implement it too e.g. computing it directly within the `For` loop and only writing the return value to column D (rather than a formula).

Comment: Works like a charm! You saved us so much time!

Comment: Forgot to ask you something, could I store special holidays on different variables or arrays and subtract them from laboral days? Obviously not considereing the newtork days you've made? Thanks!

Comment: @RayénRodríguez, have edited my posted to address "holidays". See if it helps.

Comment: It really helped, thank you so much!. If I wanted to export data to another sheet based of periods. Would you recommend using an If statement or a While? (for the sake of performance).

Comment: @RayénRodríguez You could use `Range.Autofilter` (providing pay period(s) as filter criteria), then copy `Specialcells` (visible), then paste to destination. If you do this, you may need to set `application.calculation` to manual before filtering, then back to automatic (if default) once you've pasted (so that the act of filtering does not trigger recalculation unnecessarily). My code can definitely be optimised by using arrays and doing read/write operations in one go. Just something to keep in mind.